# Event Receiver issue with updating Splistitem fields

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ms-office, event-receiver, eventreceiver

I have a problem with updating Splistitem fields only when i save as via Office Word a document to Sharepoint
in my Event receiver.

it's works when i add the document from Sharepoint.

here is my Code :

```
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdded(properties);
        properties.ListItem["Status"] = "Approved";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to update your list item in order for changes to save.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.update.aspx
shows you the full functionality.